# Problems learning C# in Visual Studio already

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've just started reading Microsoft .NET development. It includes lessons/labs using VB and/or C#. Now I got through the first lab using VB and am going to now do it in C#. I have copied everything out exactly (I'm pretty sure) but I get

> Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

I think I should be getting a CMD saying

> Tony Allen, age 32

Could anybody point out my problem here? I'm a back-end web developer (PHP) so I know about coding, I'm just new to this language (:

If you are going to edit the code below, could you please let me know what changes you made and why you made them? The more explaination the better!

Thanks!

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    struct Person{
        public string firstName;
        public string lastName;
        public int age;
    }
    public Person(string _firstName, string _lastName, int _age){
        firstName = _firstName;
        lastName = _lastName;
        age = _age;
    }
    public override string toString(){
        return firstName + " " + lastName + ", age " + age;
    }
    class Program{
        static void Main(string[] args){
            Person p = new Person("Tony", "Allen", 32);
            Console.WriteLine(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move struct initializer into struct definition. Same with other members.

```
  struct Person{
        public string firstName;
        public string lastName;
        public int age;

        public Person(string _firstName, string _lastName, int _age)
        {
            firstName = _firstName;
            lastName = _lastName;
            age = _age;
        }

        public override string ToString(){
            return firstName + " " + lastName + ", age " + age;
        }
    }
```

In C# we declare members inside class/struct definition, not like this done in C++. Please read [this msdn guide on classes and structs in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx).

Comment: Also, C# is case sensitive so the `toString` override should be cased as `ToString`.

Comment: @RichardEv thanks, didn't notice that when copy-pasted question code

Comment: Thanks man you've sorted it! - Also thanks to @RichardEv for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Also, ToString is capitalized the wrong way, it should be

```
public override string ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Constructor and Methods should be declared within the class/struct:

   ```
   struct Person
   {
       public string firstName;
       public string lastName;
       public int age;

       public Person(string _firstName, string _lastName, int _age)
       {
           firstName = _firstName;
           lastName = _lastName;
           age = _age;
       }

       public override string toString()
       {
           return firstName + " " + lastName + ", age " + age;
       }
   }
   ```
2. There is no method `toString` to override, but `ToString`

   ```
   struct Person
   {
       //...

       public override string ToString()
       {
           return firstName + " " + lastName + ", age " + age;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace Programs
{
    struct Person{
        public string firstName;
        public string lastName;
        public int age;

        public Person(string _firstName, string _lastName, int _age){
        firstName = _firstName;
        lastName = _lastName;
        age = _age;
    }

        public  string toString()
        {
            return firstName + " " + lastName + ", age " + age;
        }
    }


    class Program{
        static void Main(string[] args){
            Person p = new Person("Tony", "Allen", 32);
            Console.WriteLine(p.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

- Use `toString()` method in your struct. You don't have to override it.
- Use `Console.WriteLine(p.toString());` not `Console.WriteLine(p);`
- Get a good C# book that you can learn `class` and `struct` types basicly.

Comment: I think that the `toString` method was intended to be an override for `ToString`, but was just cased incorrectly by accident.

Comment: Hi there, where `Console.WriteLine(p.toString());` is the `.ToString` completely vital? I'm reading through [a book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/MCTS-Self-Paced-Training-70-536-Framework-Application/dp/0735626197/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1355825719&sr=8-1) and it doesn't have it - is it wrong in the book or can it be done either way?

Comment: @RichardEv Yeah. But if `toString()` method used in `struct`, overriding no need to use.

Comment: `toString()` and `ToString()` is different in your case. `P` is a struct object, so Console.Writeline() doesn't have `struct` overloading, it works like an object. Because of that, you need yo use `p.toString()` in your case. For the books, I recommend you should read first CRL via C# 3rd edition. It's amazing.

Comment: @F4r-20 In C#, `toString` and `ToString` will be two completely different methods, since C# is case-sensitive. The `ToString` method exists on all C# objects. `Console.WriteLine(p)` will cause this method to get called on `p`. By overriding `ToString`, you can provide your own implementation that will get called instead. For more information see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx